# How to clear terminal command history in VS code?

Tags: powershell, terminal, visual-studio-code

In VS Code Powershell Terminal, you can simply press up and down arrow keys to navigate through the history of commands entered, even after a restart. However, when there are same commands entered, it will also cycle through these duplicated histories instead of just making them distinct, making it hard to find cycle back to some old history. Is there a way to clear this history entirely?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a conclusion to the answers: my actual process to prevent duplicates, delete history and clear:

`Set-PSReadlineOption -HistoryNoDuplicates`

`Remove-Item (Get-PSReadlineOption).HistorySavePath`

`Alt-F7`

Comment: Previously, I could trace the command history. After I install vs code again, I can not trace commands. All the command history is gone after I restart vs code. Do you know how I can keep the command history even I close vs code?

Comment: @blackman Is your default terminal in VS Code changed to cmd instead of powershell? cmd doesn't keep history.

Answer (score 6):

In Windows platform press and hold <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>, in the pop up window write  `terminal:clear`, you'll get it shown, assign shortcut key (<kbd>crtl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>) for example and hit <kbd>enter</kbd>. Now every time you want to clear the terminal you can use the hotkey you just created.
Do the same in Mac but using <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> instead.

Comment: As a personal preference, I use ctrl+shift+K. There is too many other commands that are associated with ctrl-K and I do not use this feature that often.

Answer (score 5):

If you are using the **VS Code PowerShell terminal** you can clear the entire history of the terminal or even specific lines with these steps:

1. Press the **Windows** key + **R** at the same time to launch the *Run* dialog.
2. Copy and paste the following path: *%userprofile%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\PowerShell\PSReadline*
3. Press *Enter*.
4. The File Explorer will open the specified path.
5. Edit the *ConsoleHost_history.txt* and *Visual Studio Code Host_history.txt* files manually to remove specific lines or all the content.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following command:

```
Set-PSReadlineOption -HistoryNoDuplicates
```

It sets the `HistoryNoDuplicates` option to `True` and hides duplicate histories.

You can see the value of `HistoryNoDuplicates` with the following command:

```
(Get-PSReadLineOption).HistoryNoDuplicates
```

If you want to set it back to `False`:

```
Set-PSReadlineOption -HistoryNoDuplicates:$false
```

For more information, see [Set-PSReadlineOption](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/psreadline/set-psreadlineoption) in Microsoft Docs.

Answer (score 1):

In v1.65 there will be this command:

`workbench.action.terminal.clearCommandHistory`

> "Clear Command History"

In v1.65 there will also be a new setting:

`terminal.integrated.shellIntegration.history`

> "Controls the number of recently used commands to keep in the terminal
> command history. Set to 0 to disable terminal command history."

I suppose to clear the terminal history you could set this to 0 (100 is the default), reload (I'll test this tomorrow to see if a reload is necessary, it may not be) and then reset the limit to 100 or whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

the Cmdlet `Clear-History` should do what you want https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Core/Clear-History?view=powershell-6

Comment: Ok this actually ran into this another [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13257775/powershell-clear-history-doesnt-clear-history).

But seems to work based on one of the answer by using
`Remove-Item (Get-PSReadlineOption).HistorySavePath`
Then `Alt-F7`