# Visual Studio Code terminal commands deletion

Tags: visual-studio-code

I was messing around in python and ran a few programs from terminal and noticed that using the up arrow you could backtrack to previously ran program. I thought this was a nice feature but I'm wondering where and which file I have to edit to delete past commands?

Note: Restarting VS Code doesn't remove these commands from terminal history

Comment: This is most likely OS specific. And if you're using a non-default shell, also specific to that shell.

Comment: Windows 10, everything default

Comment: Does it print `PS C:\whatever>` when asking you for a command, or just `C:\whatever>`?

Comment: It includes PS C:\whatever

Comment: If you are using Powershell, the default, try this command `(Get-PSReadlineOption).HistorySavePath` for the location of the command history file.  For bash `echo $HISTFILE`.  See https://www.shellhacks.com/clear-history-powershell/ for more.

Comment: `PS` means you're using powershell, so google something like `powershell clear history`. Or follow advice from the above comment.

Comment: Now probably a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/71165251/836330 as there is a new command in vscode v1.65 to clear the terminal command history.