# Delete Textfield History

Tags: windows, powershell, caching, command-line-interface

If i press the up arrow in powershell the last command shows up.
Other programs delete this "history" but it seems like powershell doesn't.
I would like to know how to remove this data ( a restart doesn't work ).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PowerShell's Clear-History doesn't clear history](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13257775/powershells-clear-history-doesnt-clear-history)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can clear this history by pressing **Alt + F7**. This is the most simple way, without a command.

---

**Edit:**
Thanks to Midacts for pointing out the command for this purpose:

```
[Microsoft.PowerShell.PSConsoleReadLine]::ClearHistory()
```

For more information you may want to take a look at this post:
[PowerShell's Clear-History doesn't clear history](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13257775/powershells-clear-history-doesnt-clear-history)

Answer (score 0):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/clear-history?view=powershell-7

Using the command `Clear-History` "deletes the command history from a PowerShell session."

[PowerShell's Clear-History doesn't clear history](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13257775/powershells-clear-history-doesnt-clear-history)

"`[Microsoft.PowerShell.PSConsoleReadLine]::ClearHistory()` can be used to clear the current session's history"

Comment: I tested this, it won't work. Clear-History 
PowerShell's own history mechanism (Get-History, Clear-History) is host-independent, which is why - somewhat unexpectedly - you also need to clear the hosts's command history separately. --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13257775/powershells-clear-history-doesnt-clear-history

Comment: `[Microsoft.PowerShell.PSConsoleReadLine]::ClearHistory()` can be used to clear the current session's history.