# Run a command without leaving traces in history

Tags: powershell

I'm wondering if there is any way in powershell to run a command without logging it in the history or the up arrow "buffer".

Something similar to the following in bash.

```
history -d $(history 1) ; ls
```

Any help is appreciated!

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You can do a simple `Clear-History` to clear the entire history or to clear the most recent entry, you can try `Clear-History -Id $((Get-History).Id[-1])` but that will leave *that* command in the history.

There are other ways to skirt the history, which are well explained here: [PowerShell's Clear-History doesn't clear history](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13257775/powershells-clear-history-doesnt-clear-history)

However, I have to wonder what practical/ethical use would lead you to *need* to hide a command in the history to begin with.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! i will have to deep dive into them.
And to address your concerns, I need to use a bench of different credentials for management of different platform (Vcenter, different AD domains, etc.).
When i open powershell i would like to set up variables for all these credentials but i don't feel confident to leave them into my profile.
So far the best idea i had was to save lines of powershell to set up the credentials in keepass and copy/paste them into powershell when i open it.
Of course i don't anyone to be able to peep the history and retrieve them.

Comment: I’d say check out PowerShell Secrets Management. It’s still a WIP but it is accessible. https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/secrets-management-module-vault-extensions/

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions!
There are two issue with this approach.
1. Cred manager has its own issues (when i update credentials sometimes are not retained)
2. If my account get compromised, they will have access to all my credentials which from a security standpoint is kinda concerning....