# How to run Bash commands with a PowerShell Core alias?

Tags: powershell, powershell-core

I am trying to run a Bash command where an alias exists in PowerShell Core.

I want to clear the `bash` history. Example code below:

```
# Launch PowerShell core on Linux
pwsh

# Attempt 1
history -c
Get-History: Missing an argument for parameter 'Count'. Specify a parameter of type 'System.Int32' and try again.

# Attempt 2
bash history -c
/usr/bin/bash: history: No such file or directory

# Attempt 3
& "history -c"
&: The term 'history -c' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
```

It seems the issue is related to `history` being an alias for `Get-History` - is there a way to run Bash commands in PowerShell core with an alias?

Comment: I think you want `bash -c history -c`

Comment: @briantist, our wires had crossed in answering (you were first); syntactically, it would have to be `bash -c 'history -c'` (single `-c` argument), but with this particular command it doesn't actually work. I've also added some more info about Bash's CLI to the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- `history` is a Bash *builtin*, i.e. an *internal* command that can only be invoked from inside a Bash session; thus, by definition you cannot invoke it *directly* from PowerShell.
- In PowerShell `history` is an alias of PowerShell's own [`Get-History`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/get-history) cmdlet, where `-c` references the `-Count` parameter, which requires an argument (the number of history entries to retrieve).

  - Unfortunately, [`Clear-History`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/clear-history) is *not* enough to clear *PowerShell's* session history as of PowerShell 7.2, because it only clear's *one* history (PowerShell's own), not also the one provided by the `PSReadLine` module used for command-line editing by default - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38807689/45375).

Your attempt to call `bash` explicitly with your command - `bash history -c` - is *syntactically flawed* (see bottom section).

However, even fixing the syntax problem - `bash -c 'history -c'` - does *not* clear Bash's history - it seemingly has *no effect* (and adding the `-i` option doesn't help) - I don't know why.

The **workaround** is to **remove the *file* that underlies Bash's (persisted) command history directly**:

```
if (Test-Path $HOME\.bash_history) { Remove-Item -Force $HOME\.bash_history }
```

---

To answer the general question implied by the post's title:

**To pass a command with arguments to `bash` for execution, pass it to `bash -c`, as a *single string***; e.g.:

```
bash -c 'date +%s'
```

Without `-c`, the first argument would be interpreted as the name or path of a *script file*.

Note that any *additional* arguments following the first `-c` argument would become the arguments to the *first* argument; that is, the first argument acts as a mini-script that can receive arguments the way scripts usually do, via `$1`, ...:

```
# Note: the second argument, "-", becomes $0 in Bash terms,
#       i.e. the name of the script
PS> bash -c 'echo $0; echo arg count: $#' self one two
self
arg count: 2
```

Comment: As you noted, bash -c ‘history -c’ does not work. Also, creating env variables using bash -c ‘export test=123’ has no effect. Any idea why that is? Can’t find alternatives online.

Comment: @user9924807, any external program you  run from PowerShell (or any shell, for that matter) of necessity runs in a _child process_. Therefore, any environment variable you set in that chid process is limited to that child process (and any of its children) - PowerShell never see it. If you want to set an environment variable for the current PowerShell session, use `$env:test = '123'`